# Configuring a monitor's contrast/brightess/colours/etc

Tags: display, lcd, colors, calibration

I have recently bought myself a new monitor, now I'd had my previous screen well over 5 years now so I'm looking at this one thinking the picture doesn't *quite* look right (not bad, just different). Rather than just wait until I'm used to the new picture I'd rather get it fine tuned, *then* get used to it - so I can reap the maximum benefit.

So, can you please suggest reliable ways of configuring an LCD monitor's brightness/contrast/colour/etc to provide the optimum possibly quality image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation I found what I think was quite a useful set of test images, with useful explanations of how to use each one, here - http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/

And it seems that I'd missed some similar questions here by not using the keyword **calibration**. So here's some that I feel provided useful discussion:
[Monitor Calibration Tools and Software](https://superuser.com/questions/22832/monitor-calibration-tools-and-software)
[Should I be worried about calibrating a monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/86060/should-i-be-worried-about-calibrating-a-monitor)

Unless anyone else has something they'd like to add in the next few days or so, I'll tick this answer off to complete the question.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that if the monitor's environment changes (eg normal office as sun rises then sets) then I think calibration's not much use.

Comment: +1 for a good additional note; from what I read calibration results are dependant on the lighting in the enviroment - so when the evening sun comes in the window the colours are off compared to night time use under artifical light.

Which is fine for me, since the majority of my use of said monitor will be under artifical light, so I've calibrated it for that and will make do with the rest.

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for monitor calibration. Getting a hardware calibration device would be optimal, but there are websites out there that can help you with manual calibration via various test images.

Comment: please don't post a google search link as your answer.  if that's all you've got, post it in comments.